# how do I use a selector as a target for that function

Tags: javascript, image, function, selector, target

Probably very simple, but I can't seem to figure out how to do this:

`function mouseOver(i,x){document.x.src="img/"+x+"/pic"+i+".jpg";}`

The `x` in `document.x.src` suppose to represent the `x` selector, but it doesn't. How do I use the `x` selector as a target for the function?

Extra info: `x` is defined in a different function, it will become the name of the folder, in my case 'refugeelive'. I also want to name the target img 'refugeelive', which is the target for this function. This way by defining `x` as 'refugeelive' it selects the img from the right folder and sends it to the right target img.

Comment: If x is an id, try `document.getElementById(x).src=...`. If it's an object, `x.src=...` should be sufficient

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JavaScript, `object.property` is always the same thing as `object['property']`, so:

```
document[x].src
```

but it's poor practice to access page elements directly off `document` (and it may fail in some browser modes). Prefer to use `document.getElementById(x)` (and ensure you are using `id="refugeelive"` and not ancient `name="refugeelive"`).

Comment: I tried some things but I don't get the right outcome. I'm now using: `function mouseOver(i,x){document.getElementById(x).src="img/"+x+"/pic"+i+".jpg";}`
and in the html I got `<img src="img/refugeelive/pic1.jpg" id="refugeelive" class="floatl" style="max-height: 220px; max-width: 300px;">`. The selector `x` is defined as 'refugeelive', so I'm still not sure what to do.

Comment: I figured it had a conflict with a second function, it now actually works perfect, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Does not solve the problem explicitly, but you can build on this (or improve it)

```
<head>
<style>
div.myDiv {
  width: 100px;
  min-width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  min-height: 100px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="myDiv"></div>
<script>
document.querySelector('.myDiv').addEventListener('mouseover',
function(e) {
    if(e.target.id)
      console.log(e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() + '#' + e.target.id);
    if(e.target.className)
      console.log(e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() + '.' + e.target.className);
});
</script>
</body>
```